# get one method variable to other method in the same class and show in the route - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a controller. There have two function. Now i want to get variable(It is random string) value from one function to another function and print this value into the Route(url).

**Controller:**

```
class PrizeCalculateController extends Controller
{
      public function calculatePrize($id, $randomStr=0)
    {
        $randomStr = str_random(5);
        return view('pages.pageWaiting', ['res' => $res, 'randomStr' => $randomStr]);  
    }

    public function showPrizePage($id, $randomStr=0)
    {
        //get random string from calculatePrize function
        $getStr = PrizeCalculateController::calculatePrize($randomStr);
        return view('pages.prizesDetails', ['res' => $id, 'getStr' => $getStr]);
    } 
}
```

I have tried to get random string from `calculatePrize` function to `showPrizePage` function this way:

```
$getStr = PrizeCalculateController::calculatePrize($randomStr);
```

And if i `dd($getStr)` then i get `null`. Now how can i get this variable from `calculatePrize` function to `showPrizePage` function.

Want to make route:

```
Route::get('/prize/{getStr}','PrizeCalculateController@showPrizePage');
```

Comment: It's because `calculatePrize` returning view instead of value

Comment: I think you should pass random variable using session and get random variable using session in another function

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd how can i do that? Could you give some idea?

Comment: Why down vote here? Is my question is irrelevant?

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;

    public function calculatePrize($id, $randomStr=0)
        {
            $randomStr = str_random(5);
            Session::set('randomString', $randomStr);
            return view('pages.pageWaiting', ['res' => $res, 'randomStr' => $randomStr]);  
        }

        public function showPrizePage($id,$randomStr=0)
        {
            if(Session::has('randomString')) {
                $randomStr = Session::get('randomString');
            } else {
              $randomStr = 0;
            }

            $getStr = PrizeCalculateController::calculatePrize($randomStr);
            return view('pages.prizesDetails', ['res' => $id, 'getStr' => $getStr]);
        }
```

Comment: Now `Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\PrizeCalculateController::calculatePrize() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, string given, called in `

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud: Please check my updated answer and i have added parameters in both function

Comment: Now `Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\PrizeCalculateController::calculatePrize(), 2 passed and exactly 3 expected` . parameters issue i think :(

Comment: Now its return `null`. I think when you passed `public function showPrizePage($id,$randomStr=0)` that's why it returns `null`. In my old code in question here return null also. Don't know where is the issue here.

Comment: You almost did this. Your answer need to be delete `$getStr = PrizeCalculateController::calculatePrize($randomStr);` because you already get it from session. So just if i print it as `dd($randomStr)` then i get the session string. Thanks its helps. But how i send this random str into route url?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Use constructor.
class PrizeCalculateController extends Controller
{
        private $random_str;
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->random_str      =  str_random(5);
        }
          public function calculatePrize($id, $randomStr=0)
        {
            $randomStr = $this->random_str;
            return view('pages.pageWaiting', ['res' => $res, 'randomStr' => $randomStr]);  
        }

        public function showPrizePage($id, $randomStr=0)
        {
            //get random string from calculatePrize function
            $getStr = PrizeCalculateController::calculatePrize($this->random_str);
            return view('pages.prizesDetails', ['res' => $id, 'getStr' => $getStr]);
        } 
}
```

Try this hope it helps you. Let me know if any problem.

Comment: Did you try it??

Comment: Please wait i will try and let you know soon.